# Probability drawing a marble, placing it into 2 box and getting a green

Tags: probability

I feel like I am simplifying this problem too much and would love some guidance!

Box I contains 7 green and 5 brown marbles.  Box II contains 6 green and 9 brown marbles.  A marble is chosen form box I and placed in box II, then a marble is drawn from box II.
a. What is the probability the second marble chosen is green?
b. If the second marble chosen is green, what is the probability a brown marble was transferred?

For a I have
$ \frac 7 {12} \cdot \frac 7 {16} = \frac {49}{192}$ (probability you get a green and then a green) add that probability to probability you get a brown and then green so $ \frac 5 {12} \cdot \frac 6 {16} = \frac {30} {192}$ so final probability is $\frac {79}{192}$.

For b I haven't started because I recognize that I need to use my answer from part a so I want to be sure I have that correct before moving on!

Comment: You can continue, the first part is right. For the second you may want to use the definition of conditional probability..

Comment: Can you help me with that? I would appreciate it! I don't know what $P(A \cap B)$  would be to use my definition of conditional probability

Comment: Let $B$ be the event second is green, and $A$ the event first is brown. We want $\Pr(A|B)$, which is $\Pr(A\cap B)/\Pr(B)$. You have found $\Pr(B)$ in the first part. And  I am sure you can figure out $\Pr(A\cap B)$.  In fact you already have.

Comment: I got $P(A) = \frac 5 {12}$ so now trying to use $P(A \cap B) = P(B)P(A|B)$ but that sure seems like a complicated way to figure out A and B

Comment: $\Pr(A\cap B)=\frac{5}{12}\cdot \frac{6}{16}$, you really did already have it. In symbols it is $\Pr(A)\Pr(B|A)$, but you did not need that to find it earlier.

Comment: O gosh! DUH! I make some problems soooooo complicated and make the complicated problems too simple!

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event that you transfer a green ball - so that $\bar A$ is the event that you transfer a brown ball.

Let $B$ be the event that you select a green ball from the second box - so that $\bar B$ is the event that you select a green ball from the second box.

for part a) you used $$P(B) = P(B \cap A ) + P( B \cap \bar A )= P(A)P(B|A)+P(\bar A)P(B|\bar A )$$

so you have everything you need to get $P(A|B)$